# How to keep streaming data updated in the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reload, getjson

I am creating a Shoutcast player. Using the Shoutcast stats data, I can know the current track that is playing. However, I am looking for a solution to update it once the track is changed...

Here a bit of code that shows the current song title.

```js
var url = "http://212.18.63.135:9034/stats?sid=1&json=1&callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $("#title").text(data.songtitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
```

The above code is static, since it never changes once the stats data is change. I need to make it dynamic so it changes with the current song. in other word, as soon as the stats JSON is updated, it has to update the UI as well.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method which will be called every 10 seconds. You can change the time as per your requirement.

```js
var url = "http://212.18.63.135:9034/stats?sid=1&json=1&callback=?";

setInterval(function(){ 
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           $("#title").text(data.songtitle);
         });
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However I need it too get updated every second, so wouldn't it make the code too heavy if it requests the JSON every seconds? I am looking for the most feasible solution.

Comment: Do you have server access & update the code, then you can go for socket.io which will be very useful in your case.
https://socket.io/

Comment: No unfortunately it's only client side.

Comment: Then i believe you only have this option of polling every few seconds